# Generating TypeScript function signatures for API in seperate client project

Tags: api, typescript, client-server

Let's say I have a **server** project (TypeScript of course) with two modules included like so:

moduleA.ts:

```
export default {
   foo : function(a:number){ console.log(a); callback('whatever'); }
}
```

moduleB.ts:

```
export default {
   bar : function(b:string){ console.log(b); callback('whatever'); }
}
```

Assume those methods are made available on some sort of API that the client project can access.

In the **client** project (TypeScript as well), up until this point I've had code that looks like this:

```
apiService.call('moduleA.foo', 4);
apiService.call('moduleB.bar', 'hello');
```

Everything works fine in this manner, the call method funnels the 1st argument as a method call, and any other extra arguments as actual method parameters. A promise is returned with the results.

What I want to do, is somehow extract the function signatures on my server project and make them available to the client, so my client code looks like this instead:

```
apiService.moduleA.foo(4);
apiService.moduleB.bar('hello');
```

Or even this:

```
moduleA.foo(4);
moduleB.bar('hello');
```

This allows things like type checking and argument length to be enforced properly, while allowing underlying client api call implementation to work.

Does anyone know a pattern or technique that can help me achieve this, or am I stuck with having to manually generate files? Combining server and client into one project doesn't seem like it helps much, as the client only cares about the server's method signatures, not their implementation server side.

Caveats: This is not for a REST API, but JSON-RPC 2.0, so any end-to-end typings that are for REST aren't really appropriate I guess. I need some abstraction here. Also, I'm not working with d.ts files for my server methods, whatever I have to do is likely to involve generating d.ts files from existing .ts files.

Comment: The code for fileA and fileB is not really valid ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir you're right, sorry! edited

Comment: Also the signatures on the server and the client should be exactly the same ?

Comment: Correct, the server uses 'this' to inherit context so the signature is not polluted with anything beyond the bare minimum needed